# Material UI Paper not taking full width at small view port

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styleddocument

I am developing a website where I am using  component for dark mode display, but while shrinking below 600px  Component getting shrunk way too much and not others.

My appjs:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeChanger>
        <Paper square elevation={0}>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </Paper>
      </ThemeChanger>
    </>
  );
 }
```

Here are some sample Images :

Here is the Image of UI at greater than 700px width

[image: Here is the Image of UI at greater than 700px width]

Here is a picture at less than 600px width

[image: Here is a picture at less than 600px width]

Things I already tried
adding flex , min-width : "100%" at  component
every other component is behaving fine except  component

TechStack I am using
NextJS v11
Material Ui v5

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find the solution with looking at the entire css.

For me it look like a parent element's size constraints are blocking the child to grow. You won't be able to make a child element take up full width if the parent element has fixed size or doesn't have 100% width.

Inspect the element on both screens and figure of what css is blocking the width 100%.

Comment: I can understand that's how it seems but <Paper> component is the parent component in this case.

Comment: What fixed the issue was setting overflow-x: hidden; this seems to work for now.